# Temporary table both exists and doesn't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, sql-server-2019

I'm trying to drop a temporary table in SQL Server if it exists and create a new temp table if it doesn't exist. The command `IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.. #my_temp') IS NULL` seems unable to fine the temp table and then when the query tries to create the table, I receive an error that the temp table already exists.

This is my query:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.. #my_temp') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #my_temp 
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.. #my_temp') IS NULL
BEGIN
print 'trying to create a new temp table'
CREATE TABLE   #my_temp
( [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```

If I run this query twice, on the second time I receive this output:

> ```
> trying to create a new temp table
> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 12
> There is already an object named '#my_temp' in the database.
> ```

My SQL Server is version 2019 for your info.

Comment: If you run `SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb.. #my_temp')` you'll see it returns `NULL` after running the statement intially. Personally, i prefer to "clean up" tables at the ends of a script, not check if they exist before hand. Otherwise, you could use a `TRY...CATCH`.

Comment: `'tempdb.. #my_temp'` is not `'tempdb..#my_temp'` (extraneous space).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you. Would you please write how should I clean up?
"TRY ... CATCH" is terrible in SQL Server. It almost doesn't work. I have tried it in many occasions in the past.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thank you very much. You solved my problem. Would you write your answer in a post, so that I can mark it as solved? It might happen for others as well. I have had this problem in the past too.

Comment: The problem is a simple typo, and the question should be closed as such, not answered.

Comment: *""TRY ... CATCH" is terrible in SQL Server. It almost doesn't work."* Sounds like you're using it wrong; `TRY...CATCH` in SQL Server is an invaluable tool..

Comment: @Larnu `TRY ... CATCH` does have plenty of gotchas, especially without `XACT_ABORT ON`

Comment: That doesn't mean it doesn't work, @Charlieface . It just needs to be used properly. If people take the time to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), it explains a lot of how to implement it, and when it doesn't catch errors (for example, when an object doesn't exist, because that's a compilation error, and so the `TRY...CATCH` was never actually reached).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I might learn more about TRY...CATCH in SQL Server in future. For now, removing the extra space solved this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space between .. and the table name

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_temp') IS NOT NULL  
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE  #my_temp 
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#my_temp') IS NULL
BEGIN
print 'trying to create a new temp table'
CREATE TABLE   #my_temp
( [ID] int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ,
) ON [PRIMARY]
END
```